make use of gunicorn services with password protected cert and key file, how do i pass the password without manually entering each and every time
gunicorn startup command is something like:
gunicorn_command = (
        f"nohup gunicorn --certfile={SSL_CERT_FILE} --keyfile={SSL_KEY_FILE} --workers=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:3052 "
        f"--worker-class=uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --reload --pid={GUNICORN_PID_FILE} --timeout=0 --log-level=debug "
        f"--access-logfile={ACCESS_LOG_FILE} --error-logfile={ERROR_LOG_FILE} main:app --preload > {nohup_outfile} &"
    )

if I execute this, it will repeatedly prompt for asking pem passphrase in a loop:
enter image description here
I have executed this code:
from pathlib import Path
import ssl
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import time
import logging
import json
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

# Initialize logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# Load configuration from JSON file
config_file_path = Path(__file__).parent / 'config.json'
with open(config_file_path, 'r') as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)

# Extract paths from config
working_dir = Path(config['working_dir'])
backend_path = working_dir / 'backend'
logDir = Path(config['logDir'])
nohup_outfile = Path(config['nohup_outfile'])
GUNICORN_PID_FILE = Path(config['gunicorn_pid_file'])
NGINX_PID_FILE = Path(config['nginx_pid_file'])
PASSWORD_FILE = Path(config['password_file'])
SSL_CERT_FILE = Path(config['ssl_cert_file'])
SSL_KEY_FILE = Path(config['ssl_key_file'])
ACCESS_LOG_FILE = Path(config['access_log_file'])
ERROR_LOG_FILE = Path(config['error_log_file'])
SSL_KEY_PASSWORD = ''

# Read SSL key password
with open(PASSWORD_FILE, 'r') as f:
    SSL_KEY_PASSWORD = f.read().strip()

def create_ssl_context():
    """Creates an SSL context using the provided certificate and key files."""
    with open(SSL_KEY_FILE, 'rb') as key_file:
        private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
            key_file.read(),
            password=SSL_KEY_PASSWORD.encode() if SSL_KEY_PASSWORD else None
        )

    context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile=SSL_CERT_FILE, keyfile=SSL_KEY_FILE, password=SSL_KEY_PASSWORD)
    return context

def is_process_running(pid_file):
    """Checks if a process with the given PID file is running."""
    if not pid_file.is_file():
        return False
    try:
        with open(pid_file, 'r') as f:
            pid = int(f.read().strip())
        os.kill(pid, 0)
        return True
    except ProcessLookupError:
        return False
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Unexpected error: {e}")
        return False

def stop_services():
    """Stops the Nginx and Gunicorn services."""
    logging.info("Stopping nginx services.")
    if NGINX_PID_FILE.is_file():
        subprocess.run([
            'nginx', '-c', str(working_dir / 'nginx/nginx_non_sudo.conf'),
            '-p', str(NGINX_PID_FILE),
            '-s', 'stop'
        ])
    if GUNICORN_PID_FILE.is_file():
        subprocess.run([
            'python3', str(working_dir / 'scripts/startup_scripts/stop_gunicorn.py'),
            SSL_KEY_PASSWORD
        ])
        logging.info("Stopping gunicorn services.")
        time.sleep(2)

    print_service_status()

def start_services():
    """Starts the Gunicorn and Nginx services."""
    logging.info("Starting gunicorn.")
    
    context = create_ssl_context()
    if context:
        print("using ssl context")
    else:
        print("not using ssl context")
        
    os.chdir(backend_path)
    gunicorn_command = (
        f"nohup gunicorn --certfile={SSL_CERT_FILE} --keyfile={SSL_KEY_FILE} --workers=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:3052 "
        f"--worker-class=uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --reload --pid={GUNICORN_PID_FILE} --timeout=0 --log-level=debug "
        f"--access-logfile={ACCESS_LOG_FILE} --error-logfile={ERROR_LOG_FILE} main:app --preload > {nohup_outfile} &"
    )
    
    subprocess.Popen(gunicorn_command, shell=True)
    
    logging.info("Starting nginx.")
    subprocess.run([
        'nginx', '-c', str(working_dir / 'nginx/nginx_non_sudo.conf'),
        '-p', str(NGINX_PID_FILE)
    ])

    print_service_status()

def print_service_status():
    """Prints the status of Nginx and Gunicorn services."""
    nginx_running = is_process_running(NGINX_PID_FILE)
    gunicorn_running = is_process_running(GUNICORN_PID_FILE)
    
    logging.info(f"Nginx is {'running' if nginx_running else 'not running'}.")
    logging.info(f"Gunicorn is {'running' if gunicorn_running else 'not running'}.")

def main():
    """Main function to manage service commands."""
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        logging.error("Usage: script_name [start|stop|restart]")
        sys.exit(1)
    
    command = sys.argv[1].lower()
    
    if command == "stop":
        stop_services()
    elif command in ["start", "restart"]:
        stop_services()
        start_services()
    else:
        logging.error("Invalid command. Please use '[start|stop|restart]'.")
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    sys.exit(0)

it tried to implement ssl context by passing in the password
